# Dynamic SQL to convert text and image

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the below dynamic SQL to alter text and image columns to varchar(max) and varbinary(max) respectively but when I generate the SQL the image columns are not generating with Varbinary(max) in the alter column statement and instead come out with Varchar(max). What am I doing incorrectly?

```
USE DBNAME
go



DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
set @SQL = ' ';

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sys.columns.object_id)) + '.' + 
                        QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(sys.columns.object_id)) + 
                        ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(sys.columns.Name) + 
                        CASE WHEN sys.columns.system_type_id in (34, 35) THEN ' VARCHAR(MAX) ' ELSE ' VARBINARY(MAX) ' END + 
                        CASE WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE '' END 

FROM    sys.Tables
inner join sys.columns on sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
WHERE   is_ms_shipped = 0 --exclude Dtproperties table, it uses type_desc = USER_TABLE
and
sys.columns.system_type_id in (34, 35, 99); -- user_type_id: text = 34, ntext = 35, Image = 99

print @SQL;
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

Comment: Never mind. I was using the wrong system type id. It should be (35, 99) in my case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was using the wrong system type id. It should be (35, 99) in my case statement